# Gallery not Working in Powerview

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powerview

I am using Powerview in Sharepoint 2013. We have done a very nice powerview and gave the link to an end user over e-mail without giving the user permission. So he couldn't see the see the Powerview. After that our Gallery Screen doesn't work on the Powerpivot Gallery. We have been getting a blankscreen.  So if we upload a new spreadsheet we can't press the create powerview button. So can you guys please help me fix this ? So that we can create a new powerview and get the gallery view back?
Thank you in advance 
[image: Screenshot of Problem]

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue, you need to make sure that along with PowerPivot for SharePoint you [install Reporting Services for SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219068.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bkmk_powerview). After that you can activate the PowerPivot Feature.